# if condition concatenation in nginx conf file

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to do this in a nginx conf file but it doesn't work :

```
if ($scheme://$host = 'http://example.com') {
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

So how can I concatenate $scheme and $host in the if condition ?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with a temp variable

```
set $tmp $scheme://$host;
if ($tmp = 'http://example.com') {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching how to use Nginx's `if` with a concatenated string. I found this question, and a bunch of other articles saying "if is evil", but not offering a replacement.

And then I ran into [this question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/conditional-within-an-if-in-nginx), which led me to a solution that is much more compact and elegant - especially when you need multiple `if` cases, so I'll post it for other searchers.

```
map "$scheme://$host" $myVar {
    default 0;
    "http://example.com" 1;
    "~*(www\.)?example" 1;
    # add more if needed
}
```

Basically, this compares the first argument from the first line (the concatenated `$scheme://$host`) with first arguments from other lines (`http://example.com` literal, `~*(www\.)?example` regex case insensitive, or `default` by default), and assigns the second arguments from corresponding lines (`1` or `0` in our case, could be anything) to the variable passed as the second argument on the first line (`$myVar`).

Saving a lot of extra lines of code if you need 10+ ifs